# Can't get zip entries from DataInputStream

Tags: java, zip, fileinputstream, datainputstream

I have to unzip a zip data package which is addressed via an URL. (The URL and DataInputStream are correct!)

```
private void unZipIt(File baseDir, DataInputStream dis, PipedOutputStream pos) throws ZipException
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    String fileName = "";
    File newFile;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;

    try
    {
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(dis);
        ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();

        if(ze==null)
        {
            System.out.println("first zip entry is null");
        }

        while (ze != null)
        {
            System.out.println("zip entry is not null");
            fileName = ze.getName();
            newFile = new File(baseDir + File.separator + fileName);

            if (isSavFile(fileName))
            {
                System.out.println(fileName + "is savfile");
                new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();

                fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

                int len;
                while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0)
                {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }

                // fos.close();
            }
            ze = zis.getNextEntry();
        }
        zis.closeEntry();
        zis.close();
        // return true;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // ex.printStackTrace();
        log.error("unzipping '" + fileName + "'", e);
        throw new ZipException(fileName, e);
        // return false;
    }
```

But it is not possible to get any of the zip entries. (first zip entry is null!)
With a FileOutputStream it worked perfectly. Because of the efficiency I am not allowed to store the file on the PC.

Anyone an idea?

Comment: upps. i missed to copy the last { to close the method - but it is definitely there ;)

Comment: Can you show the code block "unZipIt" called and how do you init DataInputStream?

Comment: You may be already positioned at end of stream when you call this method.

Comment: And you need to close the FileOutputStream, otherwise you're leaking file descriptors.

Comment: DataInputStream is url.openStream() - the URL is correct!

the function calling UnzipIt(...) is:

private boolean unzipAllFiles() throws ZipException
 {
  File savDir = vManager.getSaveDir();
  System.out.println("saveDir: " + savDir.getPath());
  if (!savDir.exists())
  {
   savDir.mkdir();
  }
  try
  {
   unZipIt(savDir, dis, pos);
  }
  catch (ZipException e)
  {
   throw e;
  }

  return true;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is with how you acquire the input stream you pass as `dis` to your `unZipIt()` method.

You should not receive a `DataInputStream` but rather a simple `InputStream`. `ZipInputStream` does not use nor expect input to be a `DataInputStream`.

Also when saving the content of an entry you should only read (and save) as many bytes as the length of the entry, not until there are more bytes.

Comment: It doesn't work with InputStream as parameter too.

And thank you for the tipp. I'll try it if it starts working :D

Comment: You have to show us how you create/acquire the `dis` input stream which you pass to your `unZipIt()` method, most likely the error is not in the posted code.

Comment: URL url = new URL(fileDownloadDir);
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(url.openStream());

Comment: Ok, so all you need to do is pass `url.openStream()` as `dis` to your `unZipIt()` method, and all should work - assuming `url` points to a valid zip file.

Comment: now i passed url.openStream() to unZipIt() but the first entry is still null :(

Comment: Then the URL does not denote a valid zip file or you do not have sufficient rights to download it.

Comment: At first i saved it to a file on my pc - which worked quite well. But the zip files are really big (>3GB) so I should not save it on the pc. So i tried to unzip it from the InputStream but this does not work.